# Adding Columns in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL sp and I would like to add a column 'NetSales' which is simply 'GrossSales' - 'Credits'.  Is there a way to do this in the same SELECT statement?

```
SELECT p.PerceptionistID, p.BaseCommission, p.BonusCommission, h.WeekOf, h.WorkHours, h.PTOHours, h.HolidayHours,
    ROUND(h.WorkHours, 0) AS HoursRounded, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(c.PerceptionistID)
        FROM T_Call c 
        WHERE 
            c.PerceptionistID = p.PerceptionistID 
            AND c.OutcomeID = @OutcomeSale 
            AND EnteredOn BETWEEN @WeekOf AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @WeekOf)
    ) AS GrossSales,
    (
        SELECT COUNT (c.PerceptionistID)
        FROM T_CallCredit cc
            FULL JOIN T_Call c
                ON cc.CallID = c.CallID
        WHERE 
            c.PerceptionistID = p.PerceptionistID 
            AND cc.CallCreditStatusID NOT IN (17, 18)  -- 17 - 'Error in Customer Account', 18 - 'Courtesy Credit'
            AND cc.EnteredOn BETWEEN @WeekOf AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @WeekOf)
    ) AS Credits

    --------------------------------------------------
    -- would like to have something like the following

    SUM(GrossSales - Credits) AS NetSales


FROM T_Perceptionist p
    FULL JOIN T_PerceptionistHours h
        ON p.PerceptionistID = h.PerceptionistID
WHERE h.WeekOf = @WeekOf
```

TIA, Brian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the whole query with another like this:

```
select *, a.GrossSales - a.Credits as NetSales
from (
    --your query here
) a
```

Comment: I actually went with a temp table and a secondary SELECT statement as there are more calculations that I need to do but your suggestion got me thinking in the right direction.  With the temp table I can then simply write (GrossSales-Credits) AS NetSales.

Answer (score 1):

If You don't want to nest queries and You want to have only one SELECT, you must add another column to your column list (note that it is actually copy & paste of GrossSales and Credits columns with substraction sign between them):

```
(
    SELECT COUNT(c.PerceptionistID)
    FROM T_Call c 
    WHERE 
        c.PerceptionistID = p.PerceptionistID 
        AND c.OutcomeID = @OutcomeSale 
        AND EnteredOn BETWEEN @WeekOf AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @WeekOf)
) -
(
    SELECT COUNT (c.PerceptionistID)
    FROM T_CallCredit cc
        FULL JOIN T_Call c
            ON cc.CallID = c.CallID
    WHERE 
        c.PerceptionistID = p.PerceptionistID 
        AND cc.CallCreditStatusID NOT IN (17, 18)  -- 17 - 'Error in Customer Account', 18 - 'Courtesy Credit'
        AND cc.EnteredOn BETWEEN @WeekOf AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @WeekOf)
) AS Net
```

However I would prefer nested queries as RedFilter suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just a sidenote, unrelated to your question (comment space is too small).

Your two `FULL JOIN` are cancelled as the queries have conditions in the `WHERE` clause that remove any `NULL` produced by the `OUTER` joins.

This is actually an `INNER JOIN`:

```
(
    SELECT COUNT (c.PerceptionistID)
    FROM T_CallCredit cc
        FULL JOIN T_Call c
            ON cc.CallID = c.CallID
    WHERE 
        c.PerceptionistID = p.PerceptionistID 
        AND cc.CallCreditStatusID NOT IN (17, 18)  -- 17 - 'Error in Customer Account', 18 - 'Courtesy Credit'
        AND cc.EnteredOn BETWEEN @WeekOf AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @WeekOf)
) AS Credits
```

and this is a `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
FROM T_Perceptionist p
    FULL JOIN T_PerceptionistHours h
        ON p.PerceptionistID = h.PerceptionistID
WHERE h.WeekOf = @WeekOf
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I got FULL JOIN in there.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you just write '`a - b`'.  Here, they are fairly horrid expressions, so you use a 'sub-query in the FROM clause':

```
SELECT PerceptionistID, BaseCommission, BonusCommission, WeekOf, WorkHours, PTOHours,
       HolidayHours, HoursRounded, GrossSales, Credits, (GrossSales - Credits) AS NetSales
  FROM (SELECT p.PerceptionistID, p.BaseCommission, p.BonusCommission, h.WeekOf, h.WorkHours,
               h.PTOHours, h.HolidayHours, ROUND(h.WorkHours, 0) AS HoursRounded, 
               (SELECT COUNT(c.PerceptionistID)
                  FROM T_Call c 
                 WHERE c.PerceptionistID = p.PerceptionistID 
                   AND c.OutcomeID = @OutcomeSale 
                   AND EnteredOn BETWEEN @WeekOf AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @WeekOf)
                ) AS GrossSales,
                (SELECT COUNT (c.PerceptionistID)
                   FROM T_CallCredit AS cc
                   FULL JOIN T_Call  AS c ON cc.CallID = c.CallID
                  WHERE c.PerceptionistID = p.PerceptionistID 
                    AND cc.CallCreditStatusID NOT IN (17, 18)
                    AND cc.EnteredOn BETWEEN @WeekOf AND DATEADD(dd, 7, @WeekOf)
                ) AS Credits
           FROM T_Perceptionist p
           FULL JOIN T_PerceptionistHours h
             ON p.PerceptionistID = h.PerceptionistID
          WHERE h.WeekOf = @WeekOf
        ) AS X33;
```

If you need aggregates in there too, you supply the appropriate GROUP BY clause too.

---

*Long delay while typing answer.*